# Подключится к недоверенному TCP серверу C#

Tags: c#, ssl, tcp

Есть сервер и клиент которые использовуют самодельный SSL .PFX сертификат.
При подключении клиента вылетает ошибка, если я установлю этот сертификат в систему то ошибка пропадёт. Как можно подключится к серверу без установки этого сертификата подскажите пожалуйста

Comment: Выписать доверенный сертификат

Comment: Не во всех, но во многих библиотеках есть опция ignore certificate. Установите её.

Answer (score 0):

Вам в коммментарии Alexey Ten уже написал "радикальный способ решения проблемы".

Я хочу только пояснить, почему другое решение представляется сомнительным. Это не более чем рассуждения, которые - по моему мнению - объясняют ситуацию

Логика здесь проста:

1. Зачем нужен сертификат?

Чтобы через "цепочку доверия" обеспечить безопасное подключение, защищенное от атаки MITM ("Man in the middle").

2. Зачем нужен "самовыпущенный" сертификат? - Для целей отладки. Когда вы пишете и тестируете систему, тоу Вас есть полный контроль над установкой сертификата в любую часть этой системы, как на клиент, так и на сервер.
3. Что произойдёт, если система будет на "недоверенный" сертификат реагировать так же, как и на "доверенный"? - вся система, которая призвана обеспечить цепочку доверия, поёдет к черту.

Отсюда следует 2 вывода:

1. Именно поэтому, чтобы *кто угодно* мог подключиться к серверу по *защищенному* соединению - Вам нужен "настоящий" сертификат
2. При помощи установки в Вашу систему стороннего сертификата - Вас можно заставить "поверить в защищенность" соединения, в которм есть "человек посередине". Именно поэтому в некоторых странах, где контроль за интернетом усилен, для доступа к интернету требуется установка специального "государственного" сертификата (который позволяет на уровне провайдера расшифровать весь передаваемый трафик)

Возможно, я где то в рассуждениях "срезал углы", тогда прошу поправить  меня в комментариях.

А по поводу сертификатов - обратите внимание на [Let’s Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/ru/)